# Converting HTML input tags for rails FormHelper tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to rails and programming in general. I have a rails project including a static page with a form in HTML as follows:

```
    <span class="form-group">
      <input class="balloon" name="ex1" id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Stuff Here" /><label for="text1">Stuff</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <input class="balloon-num" name="ex2" id="num1" type="number" min=1 max=12 placeholder="1-12" /><label for="num1">Stuff</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <input class="balloon-num" name="ex3" id="num2" type="number" min=1 max=12 placeholder="1-12" /><label for="num2">Stuff</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <input class="balloon-num" name="ex4" id="num3" type="number" min=1 max=5 placeholder="1-5" /><label for="num3">#</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <button class="button" id="generate" type="button"><i class="fi-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </span>
```

I need the input classes, id's and placeholder due to the input's styling in CSS. I'm now learning how to send these inputs to a database in rails, and to my understanding it requires the use of the ruby FormHelper syntax, like so:

```
<% form_for @example do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :ex1 %>
  <%= f.text_field :ex1 %>
  <%= f.label :ex2 %>
  <%= f.number_field :ex2 %>
  <%= f.label :ex3 %>
  <%= f.number_field :ex3 %>
  <%= f.label :ex4 %>
  <%= f.number_field :ex4 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
```

My question is how do I write the latter format while preserving the id, name, placeholder, etc?

---

**UPDATE:** Now getting "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error when I check to see if my changes worked, below is my controller file:

```
class SwatchgenController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @colours = Colours.new
  end
  def create
    @colours = Colours.new(colours_params)
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to new_colours_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
      redirect_to new_colours_path, notice: "Error occured."
    end
  end
  private
  def colours_params
     params.require(:colours).permit(:colour, :bold, :bright, :num)
  end
end
```

I've triple checked and the form tag says form_for @colours and all the id's are correct as well. I'm following a tutorial intended for creating a contact page (also on a separate page, whereas mine is all in one) so if that doesn't make sense this is why.

Here is my updated form on the page:

```
<%= form_for @colours do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :colour %>
        <%= f.text_field :content, required: true, class: "balloon", id: "colour", placeholder: "Colour category (red, blue..)" %>
        <%= f.label :bold %>
        <%= f.number_field :content, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bold", placeholder: "1-12" %>
        <%= f.label :bright %>
        <%= f.number_field :content, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bright", placeholder: "1-12" %>
        <%= f.label :num %>
        <%= f.number_field :content, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "num", placeholder: "1-5" %>
        <button class="button" id="generate" type="button"><i class="fi-arrow-right"></i></button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay, I can advise you to run a separate project, create a controller with scaffold, make comparison with your immediate project and see what you are probably missing. You could learn like that too. However read Rails Guide.

Comment: There's a gem called simple_form that you may find useful: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use Rails form helper. It is just a convenient way of building forms but if you like to use your own form you can do that. All you have to do is to create a form and point to the correct action with the correct method:

You can use a pure html form which is what the form helper does anyway. You will have to specify the controller you are targeting in your form

You can start with a form_tag but inside you can put your normal HTML form input fields

```
<%= form_tag(send_email_path, method: "post", :class=>"form-horizontal") do %>
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Email Subject" class="form-control">
<% end %>
```

If you want to use the form_for helper you can pass those things as options:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, required: true, class: "your html class", id: "you html id", placeholder: "your placeholder text" %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Your form has to be changed where the asterisks are:

```
<%= form_for @colours do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :colour %>
      *  <%= f.text_field :colour, required: true, class: "balloon", id: "colour", placeholder: "Colour category (red, blue..)" %>
        <%= f.label :bold %>
       * <%= f.number_field :bold, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bold", placeholder: "1-12" %>
        <%= f.label :bright %>
       * <%= f.number_field :bright, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bright", placeholder: "1-12" %>
        <%= f.label :num %>
      *  <%= f.number_field :num, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "num", placeholder: "1-5" %>
      *  <%= f.submit %>    /// this is your button
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm now getting an error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" when I try to view the page to see if it worked, not sure why. I've updated the initial question with my controller file.

Comment: When you create a form you can pass it an instance variable as you did, but you have to define that instance variable in your controller. For example, a form_for "@example" in show.html.erb will render an error unless, you define "@example"in your controller's show action. That way, when you post to "@example", your controller knows what to do.

Comment: Aren't I doing that with:
def new
    @colours = Colours.new
end in my controller file?

Comment: Yes to do away with that argument error, you need to define that instance variable in your controller.

Comment: You don't have to create instance variables tho. If you like, you can post to paths and then you can get the form's input using params[:content] notation. For example, let's assume "@example" is post and it has its own controller with index, show, create, update, edit, delete actions. You can post to a path directly rather then use an instace variable like this: form_for example_path which will post to the example controller. When your controller gets a POST request it knows that you want to create an object because POST is an HTTP verb reserved for creating objects.

Comment: I encourage you to read the Rails documentation about Routes, it will teach you a lot about how rails understands routes and how you can retrieve information from links that you post. The whole Rails documentation is a great place to get a good idea about everything: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html